# Using smarty variable within {php} tags

Tags: php, variables, smarty

Very simple question, is it possible to use a smarty var inside the {php}{/php} tags. I know it's deprecated, pointless, not recommended, etc., but please, I am looking for a simple patch !

Something like

```
{php} 

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM table WHERE fieldid = 9 AND relid = {MYSMARTYVAR}");

{/php}
```

Thank you!

Update: I`ve tried the following methods.

```
1-$var = $this->get_template_vars('smarty_var');
2-$var = $smarty->getTemplateVars('smarty_var');
3-$var = $this->_tpl_vars['smarty_var'];
```

All give me Fatal errors, $this when not in object context etc.
I`m in the WHMCS environment, if this explains why perhaps certain things are blocked or disabled?

Update 2; found a solution more simple than it seemed, I feel silly:
    $var= "{$mysmartyvar}";

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Why do you need this? I think it'll be better if you call mysql from your php (before calling smarty). Or do you have any special reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `$this->get_template_vars('smarty_var')` to get a Smarty variable.

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM table WHERE fieldid = '9' AND relid = '" . $this->get_template_vars('smarty_var') . "'");
```

Comment: Thanks Preston, I`ve tried the get_template_vars method, as well as getTemplateVars but in both cases I get Fatal Errors such as ``using this on a non-object``;

Comment: Have you tried replacing "$this" with the name you gave your Smarty object in your PHP file?

Comment: Can`t say that I have, and can`t say that I`d know whta that even is..how can I tel what the Smarty object is, I don`t even know where the PHP file is in relation to the .tpl as I haven't built any of this and would certainly not use smarty if I could avoid it haha

Comment: The name would be wherever the smarty view instance is created, using something like $smarty = new Smarty; where $smarty is the object name. If you have no idea where this is, you could try searching (or find/replace) for "new Smarty" through the PHP files if you are using an IDE that allows you to.

Comment: I used {debug} and found some references to objects. The smarty variable I'm trying to get is serverDetails.0 , so I changed $this to $serverDetails. The error goes away, but nothing shows up now..am i on the right track with this?

Comment: The serverDetails variable would be for here: `get_template_vars('serverDetails.0')`. You need the name of the Smarty object instance. You might be able to find it using the method I explained in the above comment. It might also be somewhere near where the PHP variables are assigned to smarty (like the serverDetails var). You could try $smarty or $Smarty, since that seems like a common thing to do.

Comment: Being in WHMCS, I have honestly no idea where this might be set..I'll try looking around a bit and get back to you!

Comment: Found a solution, updated my question with it, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

```
 {php}
 $var = $template->get_template_vars('...')
 {/php}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all variables are stored in `$this->_tpl_vars`, so it should look like this:

```
{php} 

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM table WHERE fieldid = 9 AND relid = {$this->_tpl_vars['MYSMARTYVAR']}");

{/php}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get this error however; Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given i

Answer (score 0):

```
$myValue = $template->getVariable('myVariable')->value;
```

Comment: You should explain why.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the OP. It may be helpful to others.

It is very simple.

```
$var= "{$mysmartyvar}";
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
{php}
$variable= $GLOBALS['smarty']->getTemplateVars('variable');
{/php}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using "global"

```
{php}
global $smarty_object;
$var = $smarty_object->get_template_vars('whatever');
{/php}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get this Fatal error: Call to a member function get_template_vars() on a non-object  :/